# How to Force an SMTP Error for Testing - Quasar/Electron/Nodemailer

Tags: electron, smtp, nodemailer, quasar-framework

I have written a Quasar/Electron desktop application that uses Nodemailer to send SMTP emails that can have attachments if the users want to include them.

When I send a bunch of emails all at once (like 50 or so) I'm getting some errors that I'm having a hard time duplicating in my testing environment. I need to see why these errors are appearing so I can fix them.  Unfortunately, the only way I can send that many emails is if I use my live people, and I don't want to pester that many people with test emails as I figure this out.

Is there a way to force an SMTP email error so I can test and fix it?  This is a screenshot of what my errors look like.  I think I have a way to display the individual email error messages but I don't want to use production emails to do it.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried visiting the link Google's server has given you? In any case, this is most likely very dependent on the implementation and configuration of the SMTP server you're connecting to, so there's virtually no hope in replicating the error.